# What is the antiderivative of the Heaviside step function?

Tags: indefinite-integrals, step-function

What is the antiderivative of the Heaviside step function $\Theta (x)$ as defined on [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function)? I have seen somewhere it is $x\Theta (x)+C$, yet taking the derivative of this expression using the product rule gives $\Theta(x)+x\delta(x)$, where $\delta(x)$ is the Dirac delta function. This does not return $\Theta(x)$.

Comment: What do you think $0\delta(0)$ equals?

Comment: It is indeterminate, i.e. zero times infinity.

Comment: $\delta(x)$ is a distribution.  One unit of mass is concentrated at $x=0$.  If I multiply the mass by $2$, then there are two units of mass concentrated at $0$.  If I multiply by $1/10$ there is $1/10$ unit of mass concentrated at $0$.  If I multiply by $0$ then there is $0$ units of mass concentrated at $0$.  So this indeterminate form resolves to $0$.  $x\delta(x)$ is identically $0$.

Comment: Also. You can just look at what this function is! Integrate it piecewise on the intervals $(-\infty,0]$ and $(0,\infty)$

Comment: It’s important to note that here derivative means the weak derivative.

Comment: By the fundamental theorem of calculus, antiderivatives look like $f(x) = \int_a^x \Theta(x)\,dx$ for some real number $a$. Can you calculate that integral exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As given in the question and confirmed in the comments, the antiderivative is, by inspection, $$x\Theta (x)+C.$$